# Any difference between an async function and normal function that explicitly returns a promise?

Tags: javascript

My new job has a lot of functions that look like this

```
function doThing() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (???) resolve(???)
        reject(???)
    })
}
```

I'm considering refactoring it to

```
async function doThing() {
    if (???) return ???
    throw ???
}
```

But just wanted to make sure there are no differences to the two before I do.

Comment: You can use `await` inside an `async` function. But there's no difference as far as the caller is concerned.

Comment: Async functions are a bit newer, so I would check browser support (if you don't have transpilation in place). Otherwise there is no difference, `async function`s are just way more powerful

Comment: Thanks everyone. Great answers, just wanted to check :)

Comment: If there is nothing asynchronous going on in here why use either functions?

Comment: Is there anything actually asynchronous inside these functions?